# SUSY nth-omega always starts with first element

Tags: drupal-theming, susy-compass

I am styling my theme on omega4. 
On one page I got gallery with 6 elements in 2 rows.
So it looks like 
4 elements
2 elements

Each element has class:

```
.l-content .node{
    @include span-columns(4, 16);
    @include nth-omega(4n);
  }
```

The problem is that susy starts giving nth-omega style from first and each next 4 node. 
I also tried 3n+1, 2n+2 but still same effect.

Comment: I can't recreate the problem. It's working fine for me in this [SassMeister demo](http://sassmeister.com/gist/f347ddfddfc311e187c7). Are you sure the problem isn't coming from somewhere else in your code?